# How to merge records in mongodb with aggregate

Tags: mongodb, merge, aggregation-framework, records

I have a collection named "timestamp" and each time_in, time_out, break_start, and break_end has separate record.

What i want is to merge records with the same date.
From this:
Unmerged Data:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a94f3e461613268eaecc59c"), 
    "staff_id" : NumberInt(173), 
    "time_in" : ISODate("2018-02-27T00:40:00.000+0000"), 
    "time_out" : null, 
    "break_start" : null, 
    "break_end" : null, 
    "break_type" : null, 
    "train_delay" : true, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-02-27T00:40:00.000+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-02-27T00:40:00.000+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a94f411e5e2d568f1dae527"), 
    "staff_id" : NumberInt(173), 
    "time_in" : null, 
    "time_out" : null, 
    "break_start" : ISODate("2018-02-27T04:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "break_end" : null, 
    "break_type" : "60m", 
    "train_delay" : false, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-02-27T04:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-02-27T04:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a94f41ae5e2d568f1dae528"), 
    "staff_id" : NumberInt(173), 
    "time_in" : null, 
    "time_out" : null, 
    "break_start" : null, 
    "break_end" : ISODate("2018-02-27T04:59:00.000+0000"), 
    "break_type" : null, 
    "train_delay" : false, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-02-27T04:59:00.000+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-02-27T04:59:00.000+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a94f421e5e2d568f1dae529"), 
    "staff_id" : NumberInt(173), 
    "time_in" : null, 
    "time_out" : ISODate("2018-02-27T10:05:00.000+0000"), 
    "break_start" : null, 
    "break_end" : null, 
    "break_type" : null, 
    "train_delay" : false, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-02-27T10:05:00.000+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-02-27T10:05:00.000+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

Here's the image of:
[Not yet merge records.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCDPP.png)

Into this:
Merged Data:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a94f3e461613268eaecc59c"), 
    "staff_id" : NumberInt(173), 
    "time_in" : { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a94f3e461613268eaecc59c"), 
    "staff_id" : NumberInt(173), 
    "time_in" : ISODate("2018-02-27T00:40:00.000+0000"), 
    "time_out" : ISODate("2018-02-27T10:05:00.000+0000"), 
    "break_start" : ISODate("2018-02-27T04:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "break_end" : ISODate("2018-02-27T04:59:00.000+0000"),  
    "break_type" : null, 
    "train_delay" : true, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-02-27T00:40:00.000+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-02-27T00:40:00.000+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

Here's the image of:
[Merged records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEf5b.png)

Comment: It just automatically linked. Maybe because the picture is too wide?

Comment: What is your mongodb version ? You can do merge objects in 3.6. Do you merge on staff id ?

Comment: My mongodb version is 3.6. Yes merge with the same staff_id and the same date.